# IOS MDM Licence & SSl certificate (Testing)

Tags: ios, ssl, ios7, mdm, ios7.1

HI I started Devloping app for IOS MDM(Mobile Device Management) with the help of wso2 & some other open sources , But I am very confused about what are the accounts I should take to Enroll devices & publishing app etc..

For testing MDM feture Is it possible without registration from apple (How to get ssl certificate )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend to read MDM documentation. You will need to have an access to enterprise developer program to get it. It's VERY useful, because it gives you a high level overview of it.

Also, you can take a look at this reverse engineered documentation: http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf
However, I would really-really recommend to get official one.

Let me try to break down your question to multiple items and comment on each of them:

> I started developing app for IOS MDM

Generally speaking, you will need to develop only a server side. So, I would rather not call it "an app", because it could be confused with iOS application. iOS MDM doesn't require (and doesn't use) any custom iOS apps.

> what are the accounts I should take to Enroll devices & publishing app etc..

Generally, you will need Apple enterprise developer account. You will need it to be able to create MDM APNS certificate which is used to send push notifications to a device. This notification will wake app embedded iOS MDM agent, which will communicate with your server.

You don't need to publish any app for your MDM to work. As I mentioned, iOS MDM doesn't need any iOS apps to work.

I am not sure what did you mean by "accounts to Enroll devices"?

> For testing MDM feture Is it possible without registration from apple (How to get ssl >certificate )

There are some pieces of MDM which you can build and test with registration with Apple. However, if you want to work it from end to end, you will need enterprise developer account.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the MDM vendor account and a pem file to work with WSO2 EMM. Though it is open source it doesn't provide those to end users. First please go through the getting started document of WSO2 EMM. You will find the steps you need to follow to generate these certificates etc.